# Rails 5, paperclip not validating the attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am getting this response:

```
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Ben/AppData/Local/Temp/5523c88dd347d1b7cc617f632b7efdb720171021-12076-b6btes.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename bg.jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Ben/AppData/Local/Temp/5523c88dd347d1b7cc617f632b7efdb720171021-12076-1fvpv4a.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename bg.jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
```

On Windows

And I have this in my model:

```
  has_attached_file :image
  # Validate content type
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  # Explicitly do not validate
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
```

And the request just fails, I dont understand why is it happening?

Comment: Any idea what was wrong?

Comment: @MahmoudM.Abdel-Fattah Bug in paperclip i think, i just disabled it and validate manually

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did too

Answer (score -1):

Try:

config/initializers/paperclip.rb:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/bin/' # Path to ImageMagick
```